# CUDA Optimization Not Working

Tags: c++, cuda, reduce

I found this PDF (http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) that walks you through several ways to optimize a reduce operation in CUDA and I'm trying to follow along.  For reduction #5 it suggests unrolling the last 6 iterations of the loop with the following code:

```
if (tid < 32)
{
  sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 32];
  sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 16];
  sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 8];
  sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 4];
  sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 2];
  sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 1];
}
```

The previous slide even says:

> - As reduction proceeds, # “active” threads decreases
>
>   - When s <= 32, we have only one warp left
> - Instructions are SIMD synchronous within a warp
> - That means when s <= 32:
>
>   - We don’t need to __syncthreads()
>   - We don’t need “if (tid < s)” because it doesn’t save any work

However when I tried this approach I got a MUCH smaller sum from the reduction than from the previous approach.  If I add **__syncthreads()** after each write to shared memory then I get the correct result.

Are the comments about *"Instructions are SIMD synchronous within a warp"* and *"We don't need to __syncthreads()"* not true?  Or is this an old document and the technology has changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the volatile keyword, as njuffa commented below.

There's a much more recent version of the same document here.
https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf

Here's the equivalent example #6 for reference.

```
template <unsigned int blockSize>
__device__ void warpReduce(volatile int *sdata, unsigned int tid) {
    if (blockSize >= 64) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 32];
    if (blockSize >= 32) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 16];
    if (blockSize >= 16) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 8];
    if (blockSize >= 8) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 4];
    if (blockSize >= 4) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 2];
    if (blockSize >= 2) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 1];
}

template <unsigned int blockSize>
__global__ void reduce6(int *g_idata, int *g_odata, unsigned int n) {
    extern __shared__ int sdata[];
    unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*(blockSize*2) + tid;
    unsigned int gridSize = blockSize*2*gridDim.x;
    sdata[tid] = 0;

    while (i < n) { sdata[tid] += g_idata[i] + g_idata[i+blockSize]; i += gridSize; }

    __syncthreads();

    if (blockSize >= 512) { if (tid < 256) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 256]; } __syncthreads(); }
    if (blockSize >= 256) { if (tid < 128) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 128]; } __syncthreads(); }
    if (blockSize >= 128) { if (tid < 64) { sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 64]; } __syncthreads(); }

    if (tid < 32) warpReduce(sdata, tid);
    if (tid == 0) g_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
}
```

Comment: Unless `sdata` has the `volatile` attribute, this code is unlikely to work as desired. There is an *implicit* data dependency between the statements in the `if`-block that the compiler cannot detect, and it will likely happily pull all the `sdata` reads to the start of the block to increase latency tolerance of the code. I would suggest using up-to-date documentation for CUDA, rather than outdated one.

Comment: @Johnathan Olson I implemented reduce6 as well and had the same problem unless I called __syncthreads() after each write to sdata.

Comment: @njuffa Adding `volatile` to sdata appears to have fixed it!  I don't know how old that documentation is, I just ran across it when looking for ways to optimize a reduce algorithm.

Comment: @Moohasha This document seems to be from CUDA 1.1 beta, so likely dates to around late 2007.

Comment: thanks njuffa, edited the above

Comment: Thanks for the link to the updated version.  I didn't see a date or version number in the PDF that I found and had no idea it was so old!