# Warp threads not SIMD synchronous

Tags: parallel-processing, gpgpu, hlsl, compute-shader, directcompute

I'm going through the parallel reduction [example from Nvidia](https://www.nvidia.com/content/GTC-2010/pdfs/2260_GTC2010.pdf). If `tid < 32` then the threads are all meant to be in the same warp and so the instructions are suppose to be SIMD synchronous, so we can assume that `sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 32];` completes for all threads before `sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 16];` and so on. But this is not happening for me.

```
for (unsigned int s=groupDim_x/2; s>32; s>>=1) 
{ 
    if (tid < s) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s]; 
    GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync(); 
}
if (tid < 32)
{ 
    sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 32];
    sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 16];
    sdata[tid] += sdata[tid +  8]; 
    sdata[tid] += sdata[tid +  4];
    sdata[tid] += sdata[tid +  2];
    sdata[tid] += sdata[tid +  1]; 
}
```

The solution to the same problem on Cuda has already been posted ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330814/cuda-optimization-not-working)), but it uses pointers and the volatile keyword. Directcompute doesn't have pointers and doesn't allow the volatile keyword on global memory.

Comment: What hardware are you using? Note that the NVidia example assumes that you use a GPU with a warp size of at least 32 - which is true for most hardware, but not guaranteed to be true for all hardware. Especially Intels integrated GPUs tend to have warp sizes of 4 (at least the ones I tested so far)

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that. Nvidia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Directcompute doesn't have pointers and doesn't allow the volatile keyword on global memory.

Indeed, but it exposes comparable functionality as intrinsic functions. Replace `+=` in your loop with `InterlockedAdd` [intrinsic function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/interlockedadd) and see what happens. However that function only works on integers.